# Language Design: Confusion as to why an assigned variable returns the wrong answer in arithmetic expressions

Tags: haskell, evaluation

Edit: For clarification, all arithmetic expressions in the form of `integer op integer` work as they should but `variable op integer` results in the confusing result.

In the simple language I am writing, I am at a point in which I am trying to implement user defined variables. I am following the 'Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours' a guide to structure my development process. I have successfully implement variable instantiation such that the behaviour of my expression `x:=4` behaves like WYS48's `(define x 4)` in that they both return 4.

When I try to use `x` in an arithmetic expression however, I get an unusual result.

```
Henry > x:=4
4
Henry > <x+4>
76
```

At first I assumed it was adding the ASCII value of x to 4 but it isn't because the ASCII value for x is 120 and it's Hex is 78, so I know it's not that. I don't see where the mistake is however in the program. I suspect it may be in my function `str2Int` mainly due to the subtraction of 48 in it. Below is my code to evaluate arithmetic, expressions, and the functions that I used to evaluate my `x`. Subtracting 71 when the expression is `x:=0` seems to work for that case an arithmetic is fine for that instantiation of `x` but it's not a particularly optimal fix.

```
eval :: Env -> HenryVal -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
eval env val@(Atom _) = return val
eval env val@(ABinOp _) = return val
eval env (Assign var val) = eval env val >>= defineVar env var
eval env (ABinary op x y) = return $ evalABinOp env x op y

evalABinOp :: Env -> HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOp env (Atom a) Add (Integer b) = Integer ((toInteger (str2Int'(str2HenryStr (a)))) + b )

str2Int' :: HenryVal -> Integer
str2Int' n = toInteger $ (ord (show n !! 1)) - 48

str2HenryStr :: String -> HenryVal
str2HenryStr s = String $ s
```

I'm not sure of it's relevancy but below is the code that I used to implement variable assignment

```
type Env = IORef [(String, IORef HenryVal)] 
type ThrowsError = Either HenryError
type IOThrowsError = ExceptT HenryError IO

nullEnv :: IO Env
nullEnv = newIORef []

liftThrows :: ThrowsError a -> IOThrowsError a
liftThrows (Left err) = throwError err
liftThrows (Right val) = return val

runIOThrows :: IOThrowsError String -> IO String
runIOThrows action = runExceptT (trapError action) >>= return . extractValue

isBound :: Env -> String -> IO Bool
isBound envRef var = readIORef envRef >>= return . maybe False (const True) . lookup var

getVar :: Env -> String -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
getVar envRef var  =  do env <- liftIO $ readIORef envRef
                         maybe (throwError $ UnboundVar "Getting an unbound variable" var)
                               (liftIO . readIORef)
                               (lookup var env)

setVar :: Env -> String -> HenryVal -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
setVar envRef var value = do env <- liftIO $ readIORef envRef
                             maybe (throwError $ UnboundVar "Setting an unbound variable" var)
                                   (liftIO . (flip writeIORef value))
                                   (lookup var env)
                             return value

defineVar :: Env -> String -> HenryVal -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
defineVar envRef var value = do
     alreadyDefined <- liftIO $ isBound envRef var
     if alreadyDefined
        then setVar envRef var value >> return value
        else liftIO $ do
             valueRef <- newIORef value
             env <- readIORef envRef
             writeIORef envRef ((var, valueRef) : env)
             return value

bindVars :: Env -> [(String, HenryVal)] -> IO Env
bindVars envRef bindings = readIORef envRef >>= extendEnv bindings >>= newIORef
     where extendEnv bindings env = liftM (++ env) (mapM addBinding bindings)
           addBinding (var, value) = do ref <- newIORef value
                                        return (var, ref)
```

Comment: I haven't read the code carefully. But I will note that `ord 'x' - 48 + 4` is indeed `76`, which seems like a bad sign. What the heck is this `str2Int'` *actually* supposed to do?

Comment: Another red flag: nothing in `eval` ever reads from `env`, only writes to it.

Comment: I didn't notice that... So `toInteger (str2Int'(str2HenryStr (a)))` takes `Atom a` and converts it to a `Henry String` and `str2Int'` then takes a `Henry String` and converts it to an Integer, though I've just realised that `toInteger` is superfluous

Comment: @DanielWagner, forgive my ignorance but would that effect the function of an expression like `<x+4>` because all arithmetic expressions work as they should.

Comment: This whole question is predicated on the problem that not all arithmetic expressions work as they should.

Comment: @DanielWagner I will make an edit to clarify it, but it works for all arithmetic expressions consisting of two integers but fails in the form: `variable op integer`

Comment: I have my doubts that arithmetic expressions involving multiple digit numbers or negative signs (if they are supported) work.

Comment: Do you know about the `read` function (or it's safer cousin `Text.Read.readMaybe`)?  You might find it helpful. `(read "12345" :: Int) == 12345`

Comment: @luqui multiple digit numbers work but negative signs don't. I haven't implemented the negative integer side of arithmetic yet.

Comment: @luqui So I have been playing around with that function and I got my program to compile. However I ran into a problem. I got the error `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`. From reading a bit here http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses, it showed me that I didn't derive Read when making my datatype at the beginning so I'm going to go see if that makes much of a difference.

Comment: @luqui So after a lot of testing, I am at the point in which I have an evaluation of an Atom and an Integer in `evalABinOp` to be in the form of `evalABinOp env (Atom a) Add (Integer b) = Integer ((read a :: Integer)  + (toInteger b))`. I still get the `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` however. I'm not sure but maybe I would have to implement my own read function for my datatype but that seems unnecessary. Furthermore in GHCI, my right side of the expression evaluates perfectly but with the caveat that I need the following function applied to `a`

Comment: `extractString :: HenryVal -> String` `extractString (String n) = n` `extractString (Atom n) = n` I'm not sure if this would make much of a difference but I think it's interesting to note. I'm assuming that `evalABinOp` takes the `n` of an `Atom n` and lets you act as if it were already extracted on the right side, much like Integer, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have any other implementation of `eval`, any variable will not get evaluated as its value for binary operations (aside from assignment). Let's have a look at `eval` and `evalABinOp`:

```
eval :: Env -> HenryVal -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
eval env val@(Atom _)     = return val
eval env val@(ABinOp _)   = return val
eval env (Assign var val) = eval env val >>= defineVar env var  -- defineVar returns val
eval env (ABinary op x y) = return $ evalABinOp env x op y      -- evalABinOp uses env?

evalABinOp :: Env -> HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOp env (Atom a) Add (Integer b) = Integer ((toInteger (str2Int'(str2HenryStr (a)))) + b )
                                          -- env is not used on the right hand side!
```

As you never use `env` on the right hand side, we can be 100% sure that the `Atom a` cannot be interpreted as a variable, but must be interpreted as a number or string (or as undefined variable). Nowhere in your code do you actually look up `a`'s value in the current environment. Instead, you transform `x` into an integer:

```
str2Int' :: HenryVal -> Integer
str2Int' n = toInteger $ (ord (show n !! 1)) - 48

str2HenryStr :: String -> HenryVal
str2HenryStr s = String $ s
```

I neither have `HenryVal`'s definition nor its `Show` instance at hand, so I can only assume that `show (String "x")` results in `"\"x\""` and thus `"\"x\"" !! == 'x'`. `ord 'x' - 48` is `120 - 48 = 72`. Add `4`, and you end up with `76`. The arithmetic works as intended. **You just don't use the assigned value at all**. Instead, you don't even interpret the `Atom` as a variable, but as an ASCII digit of a single-digit number.

That being said, how would a solution look like? Well, something like that:

```
evalABinOp :: Env -> HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> IOThrowsError HenryVal
evalABinOp env (Integer a) Add (Integer b)   = return $ Integer $ a + b
evalABinOp env (Atom a)    op  b@(Integer _) = getVar env a >>= (\c -> evalABinOp env c op b)
```

Instead of using `a` immediately, we first lookup the value. Note that this will only work if your parser interprets a number as `Integer` in your `HenryVal` language. Note that there is no `str2Int` magic going on: all of that should get handled long before we use `x`, unless we want to allow addition of Strings.

Comment: Note that I believe that you're currently running into a dead end or at least make the solution somewhat to complex. If your project is working for a given feature set, then head over to [CodeReview.SE] and get some feedback. However, keep [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in mind, post only working code and be open minded for any feedback. Also provide context on your code; in its current form, even your SO question unfortunately left a lot to guess. Best of luck with your WYS48!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It really made a lot of my project more clear. I was under the assumption that in `evalABinOp` that if `Env` existed on the left hand side, the result on the right hand side would pass it back to the current instanced of the environment...but I was very much mistaken.

Comment: I think I may need to go back and possibly refactor a lot of the code to reduce the complexity. I apologise for the lack of context with the code, I'm still getting use to the SO method of answering in that sometimes I give too much context! Thank you again!!